# import many items using "require" keyword using instead of "import"

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to import Apollo Client in to my project like this.

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, gql } from '@apollo/client';
```

But my project setup only allows "require" keyword as follows.

```
const express = require('express');
```

How can I import all the items( ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, gql )using "require" keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
const { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, gql } = require('@apollo/client');
```